# Using FreeScale Code Warrior to link GCC object files with __eabi calls in main

Tags: c, linker, powerpc, codewarrior, eabi

I'm linking with FreeScale Code Warrior 5.9 for MPC5554, which is a PPC chip with an e500mc core.  I'm compiling with GCC 4.6.4 compiled for powerpc-none-eabi.

I am compiling some C code for my project, including the file with `main`, using a GCC cross compiler.  I need to link using Code Warrior, though.  GCC adds a call to a function called `__eabi` at the start of main, which is supposed to initialize a couple of registers.  It cannot be removed, and is unnecessary for what I'm doing.  GCC expects it to be provided by the crt.

These are my compile flags for GCC:
`-O2 -std=c99 -w -mno-eabi -mregnames -mcpu=e500mc -misel=yes -mfloat-gprs=single -mno-string -msdata=none`

The documentation for GCC PowerPC says there is a `-no-eabi` argument, which should remove this, but then if you dig into it there are a number of bugs reports pointing out that the documentation is wrong and the flag does not actually remove the call to `__eabi`.

I tried simply adding an `__eabi` function to the crt from CodeWarrior.  In __ppc_eabi_init.c I added the function:

```
asm extern void __eabi(void)
{
    addis   r13,r0,_SDA_BASE_@h
    ori     r13,r13,_SDA_BASE_@l
    addis   r2,r0,_SDA2_BASE_@h
    ori     r2,r2,_SDA2_BASE_@l
    blr
}
```

However, when I try to link, I still get the error that `__eabi` from main in main.o is undefined.  It seems the Code Warrior linker can't find my function.  I verified that __ppc_eabi_init.c is first in the link order.

How can I get this to link?  Is there a way to remove the call to `__eabi`?  Why is Code Warrior unable to find the function when I provide it?

Comment: the codewarrior assembly language has the directive `.global` to make a label visible to other files.  So I would expect, at a minimum that the first line would be: `asm global void __eabi(void)`

Comment: @user3629249 you would think that, but it expects the `extern` keyword in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had the right idea, but that I was accidentally putting the `__eabi` function definition inside an `#ifdef` block that was being excluded from assembly.  When I moved the definition outside this block it linked properly.

I also modified the provided linker scripts so they would correctly locate the .rodata.cst* sections that GCC uses for read-only data.  I am not sure this was important, but I was getting a warning from the linker, so I fixed it.

In MPC5554.lcf, I changed

```
.rodata (CONST) : {
    *(.rdata)
    *(.rodata)
}
```

to read

```
.rodata (CONST) : {
    *(.rdata)
    *(.rodata)
    *(.rodata.cst*)
}
```